# Jquery to get Friday's Date of Current Week from Current Date

Tags: jquery

Trying to get Friday's date of current week from current date (today's date) using JQuery.

Something like below:(this doesn't work)

```
var curr = new Date;
var fridayDate = new Date(curr.setDate(curr.getDate() - curr.getDay()+4));
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
new Date().getDay();  //0=Sun, 1=Mon, ..., 6=Sat
```

This is how to get Weekday.

friday is 5.
so, try this one

```
var curr;
curr = new Date();
var fridayDate;
fridayDate = new Date();
var friday;
friday = 5 - curr.getDay();
fridayDate.setDate(fridayDate.getDate()+friday);
console.log(curr);
console.log(fridayDate);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/chg07276/

Comment: This doesn't work on iPhone (other devices may give similar results) where the Location is set to UK, as the UK First Day of Week is a Monday.

As an aside, surely Monday should be the first day of the week. otherwise the term 'weekend' is void! :)

Comment: @dickiewatkins Check iPhone use "navigator", and use 'jstz.js' can get Timezone.  https://jsfiddle.net/chg07276/13/ how about this one?